# need a example about kube-proxy config file

Tags: kubernetes

When installing kubernetes 1.7.2 and a warning about kube-proxy appears

```
WARNING: all flags other than --config, --write-config-to, and --cleanup-iptables are deprecated. Please begin using a config file ASAP.
```

So I try make my own config file, like this,

```
{
  "bind-address": "10.110.200.42",
  "hostname-override": "10.110.200.42",
  "cluster-cidr": "172.30.0.0/16",
  "logtostderr": true,
  "v": 0,
  "allow-privileged": true,
  "master": "http://10.110.200.42:8080",
  "etcd-servers": "http://10.110.200.42:2379"
}
```

but I still get error

```
error: Object 'apiVersion' is missing in '{
```

I think I need some example about the config file, but I googled without any result, even search the source code in git , I found nothing usefull, please help!

ps, I found way to generate example file , just use --write-config-to command line , the example is below

```
apiVersion: componentconfig/v1alpha1
bindAddress: 0.0.0.0
clientConnection:
  acceptContentTypes: ""
  burst: 10
  contentType: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
  kubeconfig: ""
  qps: 5
clusterCIDR: ""
configSyncPeriod: 15m0s
conntrack:
  max: 0
  maxPerCore: 32768
  min: 131072
  tcpCloseWaitTimeout: 1h0m0s
  tcpEstablishedTimeout: 24h0m0s
enableProfiling: false
featureGates: ""
healthzBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10256
hostnameOverride: ""
iptables:
  masqueradeAll: false
  masqueradeBit: 14
  minSyncPeriod: 0s
  syncPeriod: 30s
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
metricsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:10249
mode: ""
oomScoreAdj: -999
portRange: ""
resourceContainer: /kube-proxy
udpTimeoutMilliseconds: 250ms
```

Comment: The error is correct, you have to define the resource and api. However this questions seems to be missing information: Can you add the complete story of what you are trying to do (services, deployments etc)?

Comment: I just want to start kube-proxy service on nodes, btw , I install kubernetes by hand

Answer (score 0):

I am using k8s version 1.10.3, and just for simplicity and testing, i disable service account in apiserver by adding the item

`--disable-admission-plugins=ServiceAccount`

And for kube-proxy, just add the `--master` item, e.g.

`./kube-proxy --master 127.0.0.1:8080 --v=3`

and the kube-proxy turns out to be working.